# Power Automate to dynamically change the body of Email

Tags: power-automate

I need to send an E-mail to multiple recipients. In the body of mail, few of the words(around 10 -12) needs to be changed every time, out of 20 lines. These words are available in column A of an excel sheet.

```
Example

**Body of Email**

Hi all,

Thanks for your email. The data is available from 12th May to 15th May only. Kindly call back after 10th of May.
```

In this, dates needs to dynamically changed based on a column values in an excel sheet.

Is there any possibility for this?

Comment: Look at [`glue`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glue/index.html), for instance `x <- data.frame(x=c("12th May", "12th June"), y=c("15th May", "15th June")); glue::glue_data(x, "Hi all, Thanks for your email. The data is available from {x} To {y}.")`.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to define your variables (or simply take the output from Excel like you have) and then just throw the dynamic content into the variable/field that contains the body of the email, like thus ...

[image: Flow]

**Result**

[image: Result]

Comment: Thanks so much!! Is it possible to directly extract values from a excel column? Like if "from date" is mentioned in B1 cell and "to date" is present in C1 , will I able to refer/access them to replace in body of mail?

Comment: Yes, look at Office Scripts. I thought you already had the Excel part working though?

Comment: No, I'm yet to check on this. It will be great if you can share an outline/steps. Thanks

Comment: You've just gotta start Googling to find the answers ...

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/introduction-to-office-scripts-in-excel-9fbe283d-adb8-4f13-a75b-a81c6baf163a

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/scripts/overview/excel

... if you want proper help, have a crack and then ask a specific question that relates to your problem.  I may not have given you everything but technically, I think I've answered your question so if you think the same, feel free to flag it as the answer.